# how to use JS lib, which has no d.ts or ts

Tags: typescript

With typescript I would like to use a JavaScript Library (AMPQ lib), but I do not know how to require it in without an error messages, a function is not declared. (newbie question)

I have tired the following:

```
declare var amqp = require('amqplib');

//later on in the class
amqp.connect(params.url).then(function(conn) {
```

complains about the connect function.

also tried "var" no declare

Comment: var amqp:any = require('amqplib'); //compiler seems to like this, is this the correct way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
import amqp = require('amqplib');
```

This relies on there being either...

A) `amqplib.ts`

Or

B) `amqplib.js` and `amqplib.d.ts`

This also relies on you compiling with the `--module` flag.

If you can't find a `.d.ts` for this library, you can start by writing a simple type definition for this parts you need inside a file named `amqplib.d.ts`.

Here is the really open definition for the library:

amqplib.d.ts

```
declare var amqplib: any;

export = amqplib;
```

app.ts

```
import amqplib = require('amqplib');

amqplib.anything();
```

You can read more on [creating complex type definitions on my blog](https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/Content/Blog/Date/201301/Blog/Complex-TypeScript-Definitions-Made-Easy/).

Comment: hi, I have the --module flag, the js file, but no ampqlib.d.ts, is there a way to have only the js file? I use a large portion of the lib, and there will be a number of other libs which will have the same issue.

Comment: You need to supply *some* type information - but it can be pretty simple. Let me add a really basic example...